# Formatting dumbbell plot and avoiding R Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector)

Tags: r, plot, geom

I am trying to make dumbbell plots and want to arrange the plots in order. i.e. retention trials on top and transfer at the bottom.[! Someone suggested using "forcats ::fct_reorder" but I keep getting an error message  "Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector)." [image]

```
data10 <- structure(list(Trial_type = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    Trial_type2 = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), GROUP = c("LRL", 
    "RRR", "LRL", "RRR", "LRL", "RRR", "LLL", "RLR", "LLL", "RLR", 
    "LLL", "RLR"), conditon2 = c("Central_LRL", "Central_RRR", 
    "Lateral_LRL", "Lateral_RRR", "Contralateral_LRL", "Contralateral_RRR", 
    "Central_LLL", "Central_RLR", "Lateral_LLL", "Lateral_RLR", 
    "Contralateral_LLL", "Contralateral_RLR"), condition20 = c(1, 
    1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), Training = c("right", "right", 
    "right", "right", "right", "right", "left", "left", "left", 
    "left", "left", "left"), Pathlength_102 = c(3.187250625, 
    2.922721625, 3.405212, 2.775334063, 2.776401875, 3.149278375, 
    2.847822, 3.03391925, 3.674062375, 2.726527125, 2.78150325, 
    3.6662945), Pathlength_104 = c(2.8958505, 2.540974188, 3.413019688, 
    2.639986, 2.675723688, 2.761517625, 2.631161188, 2.664713, 
    2.889202063, 2.6051525, 2.568229875, 2.911062813), MovementTime_102 = c(1586.5625, 
    1977.5, 2181.25, 1664.6875, 2658.125, 2384.375, 1931.875, 
    1595, 2140.9375, 1652.8125, 1962.1875, 3074.375), MovementTime_104 = c(1445.625, 
    1327.1875, 2008.75, 1312.1875, 2302.8125, 1658.75, 1589.6875, 
    1387.1875, 1627.8125, 1611.25, 1519.0625, 2316.5625), AveResultantVel_102 = c(2.40919925, 
    2.069098625, 2.010902313, 1.943953438, 1.174490563, 1.548894813, 
    1.958885813, 2.343926125, 1.904319375, 2.122309625, 1.7739885, 
    1.391745563), AveResultantVel_104 = c(2.771204063, 2.5431425, 
    2.053414375, 2.505344125, 1.298380563, 1.983456875, 2.314399688, 
    2.350340875, 2.187628625, 2.051979125, 2.110770188, 1.434088938
    ), NormalizedJerk_102 = c(1270.168699, 2099.703957, 3259.268053, 
    1152.257445, 3810.890123, 4601.918336, 1792.371775, 1288.768888, 
    2699.08162, 1650.968794, 2018.457394, 6159.567785), NormalizedJerk_104 = c(853.7034116, 
    924.8554548, 2268.966702, 675.7160839, 2442.874632, 1603.954653, 
    1010.111276, 794.1752256, 1313.813984, 1197.638788, 1039.577947, 
    3125.131019), EndpointError_102 = c(1.441449813, 1.899916938, 
    1.666946063, 1.493975375, 1.945765938, 2.001344875, 1.530830188, 
    1.197009313, 2.1758275, 1.990092563, 2.106561813, 2.593554438
    ), EndpointError_104 = c(1.196976438, 1.203483813, 1.32090125, 
    1.176485125, 1.648146125, 1.253227125, 0.86855425, 0.803545313, 
    1.502868938, 1.338789625, 1.499023188, 1.504206125), RV_diff = c(0.36, 
    0.47, 0.04, 0.56, 0.12, 0.43, 0.36, 0.01, 0.28, -0.07, 0.34, 
    0.04), EE_diff = c(-0.24, -0.7, -0.35, -0.32, -0.3, -0.75, 
    -0.66, -0.39, -0.67, -0.65, -0.61, -1.09), PL_diff = c(-0.29, 
    -0.38, 0.01, -0.14, -0.1, -0.39, -0.22, -0.37, -0.78, -0.12, 
    -0.21, -0.76), NJ_diff = c(-416.47, -1174.85, -990.3, -476.54, 
    -1368.02, -2997.96, -782.26, -494.59, -1385.27, -453.33, 
    -978.88, -3034.44), MT_diff = c(-140.94, -650.31, -172.5, 
    -352.5, -355.31, -725.63, -342.19, -207.81, -513.13, -41.56, 
    -443.13, -757.81)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Trial_type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Trial_type2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), GROUP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), conditon2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), condition20 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Training = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Pathlength_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Pathlength_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), MovementTime_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), MovementTime_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), AveResultantVel_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), AveResultantVel_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), NormalizedJerk_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), NormalizedJerk_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), EndpointError_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), EndpointError_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), RV_diff = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), EE_diff = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), PL_diff = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), NJ_diff = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), MT_diff = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggalt)

#data10$conditon2 <- forcats::fct_reorder(data10$conditon2, data10$conditon2, .desc = TRUE)
#data10$Trial_type <- forcats::fct_reorder(data10$Trial_type, data10$Trial_type, .desc = TRUE)
data10$Trial_type <- factor(data10$Trial_type2)
data10$Trial_type <- forcats::fct_reorder(data10$Trial_type2, data10$Trial_type2, .desc = TRUE)

ggplot(data = data10,
       aes(y=conditon2, x=MovementTime_102, xend=MovementTime_104)) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title="Change in Movement time (ms), * p < .05") +
  geom_dumbbell(aes(colour = factor(Trial_type)), size_x = 2.5, size_xend = 2.5) +
  
  scale_color_manual(values = c('Retention' = ' grey40', 'Transfer' = 'black'))+
  
  geom_text(data=filter(data10, conditon2=="Central_LRL"),
            aes(x=MovementTime_104, y=conditon2, label="Post-test"),
            color="black", size=3, vjust=-3,hjust=1) +
  geom_text(data=filter(data10, conditon2=="Central_LRL"),
            aes(x=MovementTime_102, y=conditon2, label="Pre-test"),
            color="grey40", size=3, vjust=-3,hjust=-0.0001) +
  geom_rect(data=data10, aes(xmin=4100, xmax=5300, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="grey") +
  geom_text(data=data10, aes(label=paste0(MT_diff), y=conditon2, x=4700), fontface="bold",size=3) +
  geom_text(data=filter(data10, conditon2=="Central_LRL"), 
            aes(x=4700, y=conditon2, label="Difference"),
            color="black", size=3.1, vjust=-2, fontface="bold") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0, 5500)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0.1,0))  + 
  theme_bw()  + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11,face="bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  
  guides(col=guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4),title="Experimental groups"))
```

Comment: The error arise as `Trial_Type2` isn't a factor. Try with `data10$Trial_type <- forcats::fct_reorder(factor(data10$Trial_type2), data10$Trial_type2, .desc = TRUE)`. Anyway to achieve your desired result I think you have to reorder `condition2` like so `forcats::fct_reorder(conditon2, data10$Trial_type2, .desc = TRUE)`

Comment: @stefan, thank you for the insight, it worked